# Refactoring a UITableViewController subclass to a UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, refactoring, uitableview

In my app, I wanted to show a table in the "full screen," so I created a subclass of UITableViewController. When I want to show the table, I just instantiate it and use `pushViewController:animated:`. Now I've decided that I actually want to show it as a modal, so I want to give it a navigation bar with a "Done" button. I believe this means that I now need to make this a UIViewController subclass instead of a UITableViewController subclass, since it will now be more than just a table. I'm not really sure if this is something that can be done, though; I've created an xib, but Xcode doesn't seem to want to let me use that xib to create IBOutlets in the .h file, so I don't think the two are "connected."

I ran into this problem once before and worked around it by just creating a new UIViewController subclass and xib and just copy-and-pasting all the stuff I needed from the UITableViewController subclass's files into the new subclass's files. I knew then as I know now that that was a hacky and unpleasant solution, though. Does anyone know how something like this can be done properly?

Also, to avoid this problem in the future, should I just never make top-level views like this in the future and just make sure everything I use `pushViewController:animated:` or `presentModalViewController:animated:` with is a UIViewController subclass? Or is it safe to do what I've been doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things you mention in your question indicate some misunderstandings. First, if you're pushing you table view controller, then it has to be embedded in a navigation controller, and thus will have a navigation bar -- you can add a done button to this bar, if that's all you're trying to change. No need to refactor your code.

If you want to use a UIViewController instead of a table view controller, you should be able to hook up your nib. Did you change the class of the files owner in the nib to your UIViewController class? After you do that, you should be able to hook up the outlets.

There's nothing "hacky" about copying and pasting code from a table view controller into a view controller. I do this all the time, rather than writing out all those files.

I'm not sure what you're asking in the last question. How you get your table view on the screen (pushing or presenting) has nothing to do with whether what you're showing is a table view controller or a view controller. You should use the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: You're correct that there's a nav bar when I push the table, but not when I display it as a modal, which is what I was hoping to do. At any rate, changing the class if the File's Owner was the missing step here; for some reason I had the impression that if I had Foo class and added a Foo.xib, Xcode would automatically make the association. After changing the class owner, things are working as expected. Thanks!